# calling powerpoint Slide using C#

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint

i wanna make a program to update a chart from excel to powerpoint.

if i wanna add a slide in powerpoint, i'm using this script

```
pptNS._Presentation opres = pres.Open(@"" + textBox5.Text + "", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

pptSlide = opres.Slides.Add(1, pptNS.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
```

but, i confused when i should get slide name to update data ..
can somebody help me ? thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
pptSlide = opres.Slides.Add(1, pptNS.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
```

pptSlide.Name (or equivalent syntax) should give you the name PPT has assigned to the slide.